# Matlab: How to solve a system of equations and choose the parameterization of the solution

Tags: matlab

I have a system of 12 linear equations in 13 unknowns. I would like to solve this system using Matlab and choose the variable that parameterizes the solution.

I am following an example showing how to use linsolve that would seem to be what I am looking for. In particular, I was expecting the solution to be parameterized by the unknown "i". However, this call to linsolve:

```
>> syms a b c d e f g h i w1 w2 w3 w4

>> linsolve([i = w1, f = w1, c = -4*w1, g+i = w2, d+f = -0.5*w2, a+c = -1.5*w2, h+i = w3, e+f = -0.5*w3, b+c = 0.5*w3, g+h+i = w4, d+e+f = w4, a+b+c = 0], [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, w1, w2, w3, w4, i])
```

is returning this error message:

```
Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.
```

where the "equals sign" indicated is for the final equation: "a+b+c = 0".

I am a total newb at Matlab. I was just hoping not to have to solve this system by hand. Advice is appreciated.

Comment: Just checking, do you have the symbolic math toolbox?

Comment: @paisanco: Running `ver` at the prompt gives: `Symbolic Math Toolbox Version 6.0  (R2014a)`. So...yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error "expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment" is because `=` is reserved for assignment and [can't be overloaded](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/158254); therefore, symbolic equations use the equality operator `==` to express a left- and right-hand side.  So all of the `=` need to be `==`.

[`linsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/linsolve.html) solves the equation `A*X = B` for `X` given a coefficient matrix `A` and a right-hand side `B`.
Since your problem is linear, you could do this, but the coefficient matrix may be large due to the number of unknowns.

An alternative is to use the [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) function, which solves a list of equations for the given unknowns:

```
eqns = {i == w1, f == w1, c == -4*w1, g+i == w2, d+f == -0.5*w2,...
        a+c == -1.5*w2, h+i == w3, e+f == -0.5*w3, b+c == 0.5*w3,...
        g+h+i == w4, d+e+f == w4, a+b+c == 0};
vars = {a b c d e f g h w1 w2 w3 w4};
sol = solve(eqns{:},vars{:});
```

`sol` is a struct whose fieldnames match the unknowns and whose entries contain the solution for that unknown:

```
>> sol.a 
ans =
i

>> sol.b
ans =
3*i
```

You'll notice that I removed the `i` from the variable list since it is the parameter and not something to be solved for.